# Docker fig multiple server deployment

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have built my application image using docker.I need to deploy it on multiple servers.I came across this tool called dockerfig.I followed this link.http://www.slideshare.net/Docker/dockercon-europe2014weitingkuo.
After generating all files when i run fig up command. I get this error:

```
Unsupported config option for web1 service: 'docker_host'
```

My fig.yml is like this.

```
web1:
  build: .
  docker_host: tcp ://54.148.161.124:2376

  ports:
  - "8080:8080"

web1:
  build: .
  docker_host: tcp ://54.148.26.84:2376
  docker_cert_path: /home/ubuntu
  docker_tls_verify: 1

  ports:
  - "8080:8080".
```

Can anybody tell me where exactly i am going wrong?

Comment: It seems the error is on the line with docker_host, if I look at the doc for defining environment variable, http://www.fig.sh/env.html it should be a line like `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://54.148.161.124:2376` can you try ?

Answer (score 2):

Fig is a solution to manage a set of containers all running on a single machine. If you need an orchestration tool for multi-hosts, then you can look at [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) or [Kubernetes](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/kubernetes).

Or, you can also write a custom script using fig to deploy your containers on all the hosts you want. But you'll have to do one fig call per host, use a different `fig.yml` per host and change the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` between each call.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the code to do this is actually in Fig. The slides you are looking at discuss a hack-day project to add this support, but it never made it into the official fig repository (hence the unsupported `docker_host` option).

You may find [docker machine](https://github.com/docker/machine) does what you want, but it is still in an early stage of development.