# docker deploy image on multiple servers

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have developed an app image using docker.I am able to run the image but now i need to deploy it on multiple servers.I came across fig which can deploy app on multiple servers.But they are all in development stage and do not know how well they work.How can i deploy my docker image  on multiple servers.Is there any tool that can be used along with docker to deploy on multiple servers.I need some suggestions.

Comment: Judging by the question and grammar, you are just asking this question again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164298/docker-fig-multiple-server-deployment. The answers are unlikely to be different. Do some research; you may find things like [docker machine](https://github.com/docker/machine) or [kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes) work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to save the image as a tarfile:

```
docker save [my-image-name] > my-tarfile
```

and load it on each target:

```
ssh target1 docker load < my-tarfile
ssh target2 docker load < my-tarfile
...
```

(adjusting for sudo, ssh credentials, etc)

You could also enable remote access for Docker and use `docker -H target` instead of ssh.